# UNIX: How to move a last created file to a certain directory through terminal

Tags: mv

I am able to get the file name of a last created/modified file in a current directory with this command:

```
ls -t | head -n1
```

then the obtained file name I use it with `mv` command to move it to a directory.

and I'm trying to do it like this:

```
mv $(ls -t | head -n1) directory/
```

But it doesn't move the file.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```sh
mv "$(ls -t | head -n1)" directory/
```